# Shuntyard Javascript Calculator with unit tests

Tags: javascript, algorithm, unit-testing, calculator

I have been writing a javascript calculator for about a few weeks. It uses a shuntyard algorithm to do order of operations. Some unit tests I have not finished yet and there is some functionality missing (e.g. no display limitations, some display errors) but the core logic behaves as expected.

My goal was to practice functional-programming principles, TDD, and code organization.

The hardest part in writing this was

- Writing in a clean concise scalable testable manner
- Which ES6 syntax I could use for conciseness
- On a `MV*` Pattern, deciding the functionality logic on the `*` pattern
- Determining the functionality of the render method

Function wise I had these issues

- Debating on what arguments and parameters functions should have
- Trying to avoid functions with side effects
- Trying to avoid multiple return paths in a function
- Deciding how to group similar functions

What I wrote below is pretty sloppy IMO but I need advice on what I can do better

https://codepen.io/Kagerjay/pen/XqNGqv

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834318/are-variable-operators-possible
// Math library
var operations = {
  'x': function(a,b) { return b*a},
  '÷': function(a,b) { return b/a},
  '+': function(a,b) { return b+a},
  '-': function(a,b) { return b-a},
}
const isOper = /(-|\+|÷|x)/;

var util = {
  splitNumAndOper: function(rawString){
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49546448/javascript-split-a-string-into-array-matching-parameters

    // Clean up data before Tokenization by applying Math Associative Property
    rawString = rawString.replace(/\-/, "+-");
    if(rawString.charAt(0) == "+"){
      rawString = rawString.substring(1);
    }

    // Tokenize operators from numeric strings
    let splitArray = rawString.split(/([^-0-9.]+)/);

    // Parse numeric tokens into floats to prevent string concatenation during calculation
    splitArray = splitArray.map(function(el){
      if($.isNumeric(el)){
        return parseFloat(el);
      } else {
        return el;
      }
    });

    return splitArray;
  },
  exceedDisplay: function(rawString){
    return (rawString.length > 9) ? true : false;
  },
  shuntyardSort: function(rawArr){
    if(!Array.isArray(rawArr)){
      console.error("shuntyardSort did not receive an Array");
    }

    let valueStack = [];
    let operStack = [];
    let isOperPushReady = false;
    const PEMDAS = {
      "x": 2,
      "÷": 2,
      "+": 1,
      "-": 1
    }

    // Convert infix to PEMDAS postfix
    rawArr.forEach(function(el,index,arr){
      if($.isNumeric(el)){ // We have a number
        valueStack.push(el);
        // Oper always adjacent to left and right num, this accounts for right num
        if(isOperPushReady){
          valueStack = valueStack.concat(operStack.reverse());
          operStack = [];
          isOperPushReady = false;
        }
      } else { // We have an operator
        operStack.push(el);
        // Need at least 2 oper to compare if current operator has higher precedence than previous
        if(operStack.length !== 1 && (PEMDAS[el] > PEMDAS[operStack.slice(-2)[0]])){
          isOperPushReady = true;
        }
      }
    });
    // Push remaining operators onto valuestack
    valueStack = valueStack.concat(operStack);
    return valueStack;
  },
  shuntyardCalc: function(rawArr){
    // Find first Operator except (-) because its reserved as a neg num not an operator anymore
    function findFirstOperator(element){
      return /(\+|÷|x)/.test(element);
    }

    if(!Array.isArray(rawArr)){
      console.error("shuntyardCalc did not receive an Array");
    }
    let infiniteLoopCounter = 0;
    let index = 0;
    let evalPartial = 0;
    let firstNum = 0;
    let secondNum = 0;
    let op = 0;

    /*
     * Calculate the postfix after Djikstras Shuntyard Sort Algo
     * By finding the first operator index, calculating operand + 2previous values
     * and pushing result back in
     * Repeat until everything is calculated
     */
    while(rawArr.length > 1){
      index = rawArr.findIndex(findFirstOperator);
      firstNum = parseFloat(rawArr.splice(index-1,1));
      secondNum = parseFloat(rawArr.splice(index-2,1));
      op = rawArr.splice(index-2,1);
      evalPartial = operations[op](firstNum, secondNum);
      evalPartial = Math.round(evalPartial * 10000000000)/10000000000;
      rawArr.splice(index-2,0, evalPartial);

      infiniteLoopCounter++;
      if(infiniteLoopCounter > 10){
        debugger;
      };
    }

    return rawArr.toString();
  },
  grabLastToken: function(rawStr){
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49546448/javascript-split-a-string-into-array-matching-parameters
    return (rawStr == "" || rawStr == "0.") ? rawStr : rawStr.match(/\d+|[\+-\/x÷]/g).pop();
  }
}

var view = {
  render: function(cache,buttonValue){
    // Use placeholder vars for display to prevent 0 and "" confusion
    let topDisplay = util.grabLastToken(cache);
    let botDisplay = cache;

    if(buttonValue == "CE"){
      topDisplay = 0;
    }
    if(botDisplay == ""){
      botDisplay = 0;
    }
    if(topDisplay == ""){
      topDisplay = 0;
    }
    $('#topDisplay').html(topDisplay);
    $('#botDisplay').html(botDisplay);
  }
}

var model = {
  getAnswer: function(cache){
    return cache.split('=')[1];
  },
  pushDot: function(cache, lastCall){
    if(lastCall=="calculate" || cache ==""){
      cache = "0";
    }
    // Grab last numeric token and check if it has a "." in it
    return (cache.match(/[\d.]+$/g)[0].includes("."))
      ? cache : cache+".";
  },
  pushNumber: function(cache, buttonValue, lastCall) {
    return lastCall == "calculate" ? buttonValue : cache+buttonValue;
  },
  pushOperator: function(cache, buttonValue, lastCall){
    if(cache==""){
      return cache;
    }
    if(isOper.test(cache.slice(-1))){
      cache = cache.slice(0,-1);
    }
    return cache+buttonValue;
  },
  clearAll: function(cache, lastCall){
    return '';
  },
  clearEntry: function(cache, lastCall){
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134004/regex-that-will-match-the-last-occurrence-of-dot-in-a-string/
    // targets last operator +÷x- and its' remaining string .......replaces it with nothing
    // 1. (\+|÷|x|-)     Seek Operators.
    // 2. (?=            Conditional check....
    // 3. [^(\+|÷|x|\-)] For any other operators until end.
    // 4. *$)(.*)/       Grab everything after
    const lastEntry = /(\+|÷|x|-)(?=[^(\+|÷|x|\-)]*$)(.*)/;

    if (cache.includes("=")){
      cache = "";
    } else if(isOper.test(cache.slice(-1))){ // if lastchar is operator
      cache = cache.slice(0,-1); // delete
    } else if(isOper.test(cache)){ // If string has operator
      cache = cache.replace(lastEntry, '$1'); // remove numbers ahead
    } else { // no operators
      cache = '';
    }
    return cache;
  },
  calculate: function(cache, lastCall){
    if( isOper.test(cache.slice(-1)) || cache.slice(-1) == "."){
      return cache;
    }
    let tempArr = util.splitNumAndOper(cache);

    // Edsger Dijkstra - Shuntyard Algorithm
    tempArr = util.shuntyardSort(tempArr);
    tempArr = util.shuntyardCalc(tempArr);
    cache = cache + "=" + tempArr.toString();
    return cache;
  },
};

// Display, Read, Update, Destroy
// VIEWS + CONTROLLER IN JQUERY
$(document).ready(function(){
  let cache = '';
  let lastCall = 'clearAll'; // Assume last functionCall is a hard reset
  // Condense down into one click button
  $("button").on("click", function(){
    let buttonValue = $(this).attr("value");
    switch(buttonValue) {
      // Numbers
      case '.':
        cache = model.pushDot(cache, lastCall);
        lastCall = "pushDot";
        break;
      case '0':
      case '1':
      case '2':
      case '3':
      case '4':
      case '5':
      case '6':
      case '7':
      case '8':
      case '9':
        cache = model.pushNumber(cache, buttonValue, lastCall);
        lastCall = "pushNumber";
        break;
      case 'x':
      case '÷':
      case '-':
      case '+':
        cache = model.pushOperator(cache, buttonValue, lastCall);
        lastCall = "pushOperator";
        break;
      case 'AC':
        cache = model.clearAll(cache, lastCall);
        lastCall = "clearAll";
        break;
      case 'CE':
        cache = model.clearEntry(cache, lastCall);
        lastCall = "clearEntry";
        break;
      case '=':
        cache = model.calculate(cache, lastCall);
        lastCall = "calculate";
        break;
      default:
        console.log('ERROR DEFAULT CASE SHOULD NOT RUN!');
        break;
    }
    view.render(cache,buttonValue);

    if(lastCall == "calculate"){
      cache = model.getAnswer(cache);
    }
  });
});


// TESTS


// MOCHA - test

// UI
mocha.setup('bdd')

mocha.setup({
 ui:'bdd',

})

// CHAI
var assert = chai.assert;
var expect = chai.expect;
var should = chai.should();

// Based on http://yeoman.io/contributing/testing-guidelines.html

describe('MODEL', function(){
 describe('getAnswer', function(){
  it('grab number token after =', function(){
   assert.equal("99",model.getAnswer("44+55=99"));
  })
 })

 describe("pushDot", () =>{
  it('forbid multiple "." for one token', () =>{
   assert.equal("9.99",model.pushDot("9.99"));
  })
  it('add dot if none present', () =>{
   assert.equal("999x9.",model.pushDot("999x9"));
  })
  it('add zero if empty cache', () =>{
   assert.equal("0.",model.pushDot(""));
  })
  it('reset to zero if calculate lastcall', () =>{
   assert.equal("0.",model.pushDot("999","calculate"));
  })
  it('limit one "." per token', function(){
   assert.equal("12.34+56.",model.pushDot("12.34+56"));
  })
 })
 describe("pushNumber", () =>{
  it("push number as a char", () =>{
   assert.equal("9",model.pushNumber("", 9));
  })
  it("concatenate as chars not add", () =>{
   assert.equal("99", model.pushNumber('9', '9'));
  })
  it('reset if lastCall is calculate', () =>{
   assert.equal("5",model.pushNumber("999","5","calculate"));
  })
 })

 describe("pushOperator", () =>{
  it('forbid sequential operators', () =>{
   assert.equal("999+555+", model.pushOperator("999+555+","+"));
  })
  it('forbid operators on empty cache', () =>{
   assert.equal("",model.pushOperator("","+"));
  })
  it('allow swappable operators', () => {
   assert.equal("123+", model.pushOperator("123-", "+"));
  })
 })

 describe("clearAll", () =>{
  it("clear everything", () =>{
   assert.equal("", model.clearAll("555+555"));
  })
 })

 describe("clearEntry", () =>{
  it("delete all if no operators", () =>{
   assert.equal("", model.clearEntry("5555"));
  })
   it("delete operator if cache's last char", () =>{
   assert.equal("555",model.clearEntry("555+"));
  })
  it("delete number token before operator",() =>{
   assert.equal("555+",model.clearEntry("555+444"));
  })
  it('delete all if calculate lastcall', () =>{
   assert.equal("",model.clearEntry("5+5=10"));
  })
 })

 describe("calculate", () =>{
  it("do order of operations", () =>{
   assert.equal("5+5=10",model.calculate("5+5"));
  })
  it('handle 1 float calc',()=>{
   assert.equal("12.34+5=17.34", model.calculate("12.34+5"));
  })
  it('handle 2 float calc', () => {
   assert.equal("6.6+3.3=9.9", model.calculate("6.6+3.3"));
  })
  it('forbid incomplete operation', () => {
   assert.equal("6+", model.calculate("6+"));
  })
 })
}) // END MODEL
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
describe('VIEW', function(){
 describe("render", () =>{
  it('throw "Digit Limit Met" if lastNumSeq > 9 chars', () =>{
  })
  it('throw "Digit Limit Met" if calculation > 9 chars', () =>{
  })
  it('throw "Digit Limit Met" if cache > 26 char', () =>{
  })
  it('show 0 if cache is blank', () =>{
  })
  it('render curBuffer after Clearall or clearEntry', () =>{
  })
 })
 describe('render CACHE RESETS', () =>{
  it('return the number after "=" if it is present', () =>{
  })
 })
}) // END VIEW
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
describe('UTIL', function(){
 describe("splitNumAndOper", () =>{
  it('do simple math', () =>{
   assert.deepEqual([6,'+',4,'+',3], util.splitNumAndOper("6+4+3"));
  })
  it('tokenize negative numbers', () =>{
   assert.deepEqual([-1,'+',7], util.splitNumAndOper('-1+7'));
  })
  it('tokenize decimal numbers', function(){
   assert.deepEqual([12.34, '+', 5], util.splitNumAndOper('12.34+5'));
  })
 })

 describe('shuntyardSort', () =>{
  it('convert infix to sorted postfix', () =>{
   const infix = [1,'+',2,'x',3,'+',4];
   const postfix = [1,2,3,'x','+',4,'+'];
   assert.deepEqual(postfix, util.shuntyardSort(infix));
  })
 })
 describe('shuntyardCalc', () =>{
  it('calculate postfix', () =>{
    const sortedPostfix = [1,2,3,'x','+',4,'+'];
    assert.equal(11, util.shuntyardCalc(sortedPostfix));
  })
  it('calculate postfix with float values', () => {
   assert.equal(17.34,util.shuntyardCalc([12.34, 5, "+"]));
  })
  it('calculate postfix with negative numbers', () => {
   assert.equal(-1,util.shuntyardCalc([2,-3,"+"]));
  })
 })

 describe('grabLastToken', () =>{
  it('grab last numeric token', () =>{
   assert.equal("123",util.grabLastToken("99999+123"));
  })
  it('do nothing if arg is empty', () =>{
   assert.equal("",util.grabLastToken(""));
  })
  it('return operator if last char', () =>{
   assert.equal("+",util.grabLastToken("99+"));
  })
  it('handle floats', () =>{
   assert.equal("0.",util.grabLastToken("0."));
  })
 })
}) // END UTIL


// RUN MOCHA
mocha.run()
```

```css
/*********************** MOCHA TDD STYLES ****************/
.error {
  max-height: 25px !important;
}
/*********************** GLOBAL ****************/
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
h2#title {
  margin: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}
.calculator {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #dfd8d0;
  /* light pink */
}
.display {
  background-color: #c3c2ab;
  /* retro green */
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.display #output {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.display #entry {
  color: grey;
}
.display p {
  margin: 0px;
}
/*********************** BUTTONS ****************/
/* https://gridbyexample.com/examples/example19/ */
.buttons {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 50px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 20%);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.buttons button {
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 110%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.buttons button[value="AC"], .buttons button[value="CE"] {
  background-color: #a72d45;
  /* dark red */
}
.buttons #equal-button {
  grid-column: 0.8;
  grid-row: 0.66667;
}
.buttons #zero-button {
  grid-row: 0.83333;
  grid-column: 0.33333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bootstrap.css"/> -->
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/2.2.5/mocha.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="calculator">
      <!-- TITLE -->
      <h2 id="title">Electronic Calculator</h2>
      <!-- DISPLAY -->
      <div class="display">
        <p id="topDisplay">0</p>
        <p id="botDisplay">0</p>
      </div>
      <!-- BUTTONS -->
      <div class="buttons"> <!-- button order from topleft to bottom right-->
        <button value="AC">AC</button>
        <button value="CE">CE</button>
        <button value="÷">÷</button>
        <button value="x">X</button>
        <button value="7" class="num">7</button>
        <button value="8" class="num">8</button>
        <button value="9" class="num">9</button>
        <button value="-">-</button>
        <button value="4" class="num">4</button>
        <button value="5" class="num">5</button>
        <button value="6" class="num">6</button>
        <button value="+">+</button>
        <button value="1" class="num">1</button>
        <button value="2" class="num">2</button>
        <button value="3" class="num">3</button>
        <button value="=" id="equal-button">=</button> <!-- grid case -->
        <button value="0" class="num" id="zero-button" >0</button> <!-- grid case -->
        <button value=".">.</button>
      </div>
      <!-- end buttons-->
    </div>
    <!--end calculator -->
  </div>
  <!-- end container -->
  <div id="mocha"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/2.2.5/mocha.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/2.3.0/chai.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.test.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I think I'll just have to read addy's design pattern book, and reverse engineer how other javascript libraries organize their code (e.g. lodash)

Comment: as side note most of the conventions I used here were based on functional programming and things i learned in watchandcode.com

Comment: also i ended up going overboard on unit tests , this was the first program I had started learning TDD /BDD, so I understand now its pitfalls whenever I had to refactor and had to rewrite every test as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would maybe suggest that the tests currently focus on the "happy path" and some other test might help highlight a few other bugs/features.

e.g. after performing `calculate` if another `calculate` operation is performed the previous expression is lost. Not sure if thats a bug or feature, but i think shows the kind of thing i'm talking about.

i would also be tempted to join the `isOper` and `operations` somehow so that its a "single" change in order to add a new operation, maybe something like...

```
var operations = {
  'x': { apply: function(a,b) { return b*a}, match: /x/ },
  '÷': { apply: function(a,b) { return b/a}, match: /÷/ },
  '+': { apply: function(a,b) { return b+a}, match: /+/ },
  '-': { apply: function(a,b) { return b-a}, match: /-/ },
}
```

Comment: I didn't have calculate remember anything, I purposely made it that way to have a more "functional" programming style, e.g. everything got passed to functions only. In hindsight, writing this calculator made me realize that writing logic this way is unnatural since the natural flow of things tend to generally follow a more OOP approach. E.g., actual calculators write things to memory, etc. 

thanks for the input though. I didn't think about joining `isOper` to add a new operation. 

I'm going to later rewrite the calculator in React framework though